# How Integrate existing wordpress blog into a new web-site?

Tags: php, wordpress, migration

I had a wordpress blog which was hosted in the public_html directory but in order to add more features I have developed a seperate web-site. I have a new index page and several other pages to serve my needs. My problem is that I can not just put the wordpress into a new directory like blog because I would like to keep all my links and content same. So I would like to keep the wordpress blog but I also would like to have a new index page. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can configure a new directory index in apache, e.g. index2.php and then this should work out of the box.

Comment: @hakre I did that but existing links still go to new directory index...

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? To change the homepage?

Comment: @hakre I also want the existing links to point to the right blog posts. Is there a way workaround for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move your wordpress install into a new folder, no problem.  Just make sure to update the paths in the wordpress config, otherwise the links won't work correctly.

If you've linked to blog pages in blog posts, you'll have to edit them manually.

See [Moving Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) and [Moving a root install into it's own directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) (they're different processes, it sounds like you want the first link, but read the second just in case).

If you want external links to continue to work, you could either (a) try to catch them and redirect with URL Rewrite rules in .htaccess, or (b) write a custom 404 error page in something like PHP that would redirect them.

Comment: it is installed in the root so it is showing up whenever someone types www.mydomain.com, if I move the root install into it's own directory will I be able to hold the same links for my posts and everything?

Comment: Not without some extra work.  I just updated my answer to suggest what steps you might take.  The rewrite rules wouldn't be too difficult

Comment: I had a url rewriter plugin something like that so it goes to domainname.com/url-generated-from-post-title How can I write a rewrite for all the posts?